# Ruby: Repeating a Method Multiple Times and Collecting Results in an Array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a method that returns a hash. I want to repeat through this method five times, collecting the results into an array. Right now, I'm trying it like this:

```
votes = 5.times.collect{ create_vote }.inject{|memo, vote| memo << vote}
```

This doesn't work, and I believe it's failing because memo isn't an array. Is there another approach I could take to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

```
votes = 5.times.collect { create_vote }
```

More generally, use `each_with_object`:

```
votes = 5.times.collect { create_vote }.each_with_object([]) {|o,memo| memo << o }
```

`each_with_object` is a method added because Ruby Core found that using `inject` in the way you intended to use it was very common.

Comment: `inject([]){|memo, vote| memo << vote}` is fine (because `memo<<vote` returns `memo`). But when memo is a hash and you do something like `memo[vote]=true` in the block, it stops working (because it returns `true`, not `memo`). That's when `each_with_object` comes in handy.

Comment: Indeed, but your intentions are clearer if you use the right method.

Answer (score 3):

Use #map on a range instead of #times on a fixnum

```
(0..5).map { create_vote }
```

Or, map an array from the times

```
5.times.map { create_vote }
```

Each will give you an array with 5 elements.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
votes = (1..5).collect { create_vote }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the accepted answer, but then [Rubocop](http://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) told me that it would be faster to use `Array.new` as in:

```
votes = Array.new(5) { create_vote }
```